# What's the state of developing iOS apps in Linux?

Tags: ios, linux, swift, open-source

I thought this would be the appropriate community to ask this question.

Back when Apple had their developer's conference over the summer, I was aware that they were going to make Swift open source.

I was under the impression that Xcode would not be ported to Linux, but I was under the understanding that some entity would create a development program to imitate Xcode.

Therefore, I am wondering about new developments in this situation.

Does anyone have any more current knowledge about this topic or any experiences with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here.

Swift *the programming language* [is open source](https://swift.org).

It doesn't mean that iOS or OS X frameworks, like Cocoa, UIKit, etc, are available in Linux - Apple didn't announce that.

When you make an app for iOS using Swift, you have to import UIKit and other libraries - those are the iOS parts.

Swift is just the language - you can already make an iOS app with Ruby, Objective-C, JavaScript, etc, using these same libraries.

Comment: It's a simple concept but it's hard to explain. If someone find better words...