# What type of apps can we create within Linux using Swift (Open Source)

Tags: ios, linux, swift, macos

With the announcement [release](https://swift.org/) of Swift as open source a question came to my mind. Apparently the language/compiler supports Linux besides the obvious Apple different operating systems, but what kind of apps can really be created in Linux?

What type of apps can we create within Linux using Swift, iOS, OSX, etc. apps or only Linux apps?

Or better yet, since this may be to early the question could be... what kind of apps are we going to be able to build in Linux in the future?

Comment: *"what kind of apps are we going to be able to build in Linux in the future"* –  this seems to be a vague and speculative question to me, we cannot guess the future.

Comment: `Foundation` will be available, but Apple didn't announce anything about porting iOS/OSX frameworks outside the Apple platforms. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33466863/2227743

Comment: I guess anything you could have make with Linux before Swift, you can make with Swift too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift is a programming language, not to be confused with a software library, such as UIKit, or an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), such as Xcode or Microsoft Visual Studio.

To put it succinctly, I think in the near future we can only expect to write in Swift the kind of applications we are able to write in C and C++ on Linux.  The downside of Swift: it's tricky to integrate with C and C++ code.  See, e.g., http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html and http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/callback_void.html.  The advantage: it's simpler to use than C and C++.