# Significance of Swift on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, swift2, open-source

As Apple has open sourced Swift,I want to know what does this really mean for non-OS X users? Can we develop and submit apps for Apple devices from a linux based distro?
Anyway what are the steps required to compile and run Swift code on Debian?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466829/whats-the-state-of-developing-ios-apps-in-linux?rq=1 // Compile from the sources you find at github.com/apple (there's binary packages but only for Ubuntu at this time)