# How to import XCode project to linux?

Tags: linux, xcode, swift

I have an XCode project with SWIFT programming language, I would like to build it on Linux.

How can I build this project on linux?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33466863/2227743. In short: you can't. Although you can compile pure Swift in Linux with the new open source compiler, you can't compile an Xcode project or any code which uses iOS or OS X frameworks.

Comment: @eric-d, I just need to run my SWIFT project on linux, which originally was OS X project. I don't know how to build it because it has .xib files for GUI.

Comment: I've already answered. Swift is the programming language, and it's the only part working on Linux (with part of the Foundation framework). You won't be able to compile anything else, and certainly not an OS X project which needs OS X libraries and OS X interfaces. On Linux, for now, it's only pure Swift (with or without bits of Foundation), no iOS or OS X libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use the xcode project on linux.

You can run swift on linux so you can copy the swift files from the xcodeproject and build them after installing swift compiler on linux. Also, UIKit is not available on linux so you cannot use any code that needs to import UIKit. Foundation is available but it is not completely available eg. NSJSONSerailization is not yet available on linux.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
My swift project is on OS X, it uses user interfaces, network and JSON classes.
I know how to build a swift source file. But my project contains other files like .xib.

Comment: As mentioned above, only swift is available on linux. Cocoa and ios frameworks are not and hence you cannot compile xib file on linux.